# Bar chart in R while controlling for covariate

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataset containing income, age, gender and position in the company.

I want to create a bar-chart which shows the average income for every position per gender in the company while controlling / correcting for age.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this in the correct way.

It would be very nice if someone could verify if this is the correct way to correct for a covariate in a bar-chart.

Thank you very much (in advance),

#### Code

Basically I make groups of Position Age and Gender, then calculate the mean. After that I make groups for just Position and Gender and take the average of those new groups.

```
plot_data %>%  
  # age as qualitative
  mutate(Age = fct_collapse(as.character(Age), 
                                 `< 30`  = as.character(c(26, 27, 29, 30)),
                                 `31-35` = as.character(seq(31, 35)),
                                 `36-40` = as.character(seq(36, 40)),
                                 `41-45` = as.character(seq(41, 45)),
                                 `46-50` = as.character(seq(46, 50)),
                                 `51-55` = as.character(seq(51, 55)),
                                 `56-60` = as.character(seq(56, 60)),
                                 `61-65` = as.character(seq(61, 65)),
                                 `65 >`  = as.character(c(65:69, 71, 75)))) %>% 
  mutate(month_income = year_income / 12) %>% 
  group_by(Position, Age, Gender) %>% 
  summarise(mean_po_age_gen = mean(month_income)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # correct for age
  group_by(Position, Gender) %>% 
  mutate(month_income_control = mean(mean_po_age_gen)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Position, - month_income_control), y = month_income_control)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Gender), position = "dodge", 
           stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  labs(y = "Monthly income", x = "position",
       title = "Monthly income corrected for age") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: basically you cut the age into groups, calculate the within mean for each position and gender group, then take the means of this and plot

Comment: your question is not very clear... because what constitutes a good way to control? What you are doing is basically weighing each age group equally.. which to a certain extent is ok. i don't see how control or covariate applies here

Comment: I mean that I want to see what the income differences are between males and females and since (I know that) variable age plays an role in income I want to correct for this effect. I want to see the effect of gender on income, in such a way that the effect of age is taken out. Is this more clear?

Comment: No it's not clear. What is the expected output? What constitutes controlling it well? We don't know your data. I suggest you can make your plot above, faceted on age group. This will tell you whether the trend persist across or age groups or is specific for one. That is much easier to explain or interpret than the calculations you have above

Comment: Then I will follow your suggestion. Thanks for your time (: